# Show that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{y + \sin x}{x + \sin y}$ does not exist.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Show that the limit

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \dfrac{y + \sin x}{x + \sin y}$$

does not exist. I tried using two-path test but all of them gave the same value $1$. I tried using paths $y = 0, y = kx, y = \sin x$ but all of them give limit $1$. Since this is the only method taught as of now, I would like to know how I can use two-path test to show this.

Comment: Is this function even defined in some deleted neighborhood of the origin?

Comment: @Mark I don't think it would matter. $(0,0)$ is a limit point of the domain, so you can compute the limit inside that domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y=-x$.

Thus, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{-x+\sin{x}}{x-\sin{x}}=-1.$$

But for $y=x$ we obtain:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x+\sin{x}}{x+\sin{x}}=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

If you go along the path $y=-x$

$$\frac{-x+\sin x}{x+\sin(-x)} = -1$$

therefore the limit does not exist.

Comment: Why so, with a single path?

Comment: @enzotib OP already computed another path

Comment: Ok, right, but probably it's worth mentioning

Comment: @enzotib No thanks. In other answers building off OP's work is encouraged, I don't see why I have to change that style now.